# Invalid escape sequence in Java expression

Tags: java

I have the following expression in Java that allows me to load a native library:

```
String route = System.getenv("ProgramFiles");
System.load(route + "\\MyLib\\lib.dll");
```

When I launch it my Java application says the following:

> Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \ )

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I made an edit to the question. I can't do so... The `route` string has the \\ bar format...

Comment: Why negative votes? Please, explain...

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with your current code. Anyway try using `/` instead of ``\`` (written as ``\\``), Java threads them identically if they are part of file location.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Those exact lines in an empty main function compile just fine. https://ideone.com/oHxfIi

Comment: @Sonhja It works for me using same code with different dll file ! I think the error in the rest of your code not in this 2 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(System.getenv("ProgramFiles"));
builder.append("\\MyLib\\lib.dll");
System.load(builder.toString().replace("\\", "/"));
```

The replacement of the `\\` should fix your problem.